# Is a good practice to use min and max height width for page content?

Tags: html, css, viewport

I found out that using min-width,max-width,min-height,max-height and the vw,vh measurements i can control the size of the elements on every resolution.

For example:

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,body{
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
body{
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 18px;
    color: #333;
    background-color: #f4f6f7;
}
#container{
    background-color: #fff;
    -moz-border-radius: 0.4vw;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0.4vw;
    border-radius: 0.4vw;
    border: 0.1vw solid rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0.3vw 0.3vw 0.3vw rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0.3vw 0.3vw 0.3vw rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
    box-shadow: 0.3vw 0.3vw 0.3vw rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
    width: 70vw;
    min-width: 70vw;
    max-width: 70vw;
    min-height: 100vh;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

This container will be 100% of the view-port height,no matter how big or small the user resolution is.It's size is static.Same happens if I do the same thing with the container content.Isn't this a kind of responsive? If it looks the same on every resolution,then it should be,I've tested it and it works.But this looks way too easy and it have to be something wrong about it,or not.

I need some opinions if it's a good idea to work this way or not, and if is not, why?

Comment: Did you check what happens when the user's device/window has a different aspect ratio or orientation? How would you size texts? Or raster image? How about retina-level screens? min/max height/width is just one tool in the toolbox to achieve responsive layouts, and yes you can use it to limit overstretching. Whether it is good practice or not really boils down to whether or not it achieves your objectives. Do you need to serve users with 16000 pixel wide screen?

Comment: @LieRyan , i've tested it on different devices and diferrent resolution,from 800x600 to 1920x1080 and it looks the same. Obviously there are big difference between 800x600 and 1920x1080 at aspect ratio,but i dont think i can do something about it.And it works on images,tables,texts,etc too.

Comment: @Shikkediel ,as an example,setting a div to 80% width makes it 80% of the browser width but it can get bigger if you add some in-line content that exceeds it's size.In this case you should use max-width.Also if you dont have enough content the div can be smaller than 80% and then you should use min-width.

Comment: Repost - messed the text up a bit. I'm not really getting this one to be honest... yes, minimum and maximum sizes can help make things responsive but if the same value is used on the basic property (width or height) then it is to no effect. In the CSS rule for `html, body` the first height property is abundant and in the one for `#container` min and max don't do anything. Even more so, because `#container` has a minimum height of 100vh the rules for `html, body` aren't needed.

Comment: That is true, @Petru Lebada but it is not what you posted as an example. You'd have to change the format to pixels for example - sticking with percentage or viewport units won't work.

Comment: The html,body rule is useless indeed,but in the container the min-height it's important to keep the height of the container at the full height of the viewport(in case the content won't fill the entire viewport).Max and min width are also important to be sure the content won't change it's size.

Comment: Agree with the first but can't with the second (it'll always be 70vw with it's basic width property). ;-)

Comment: Indeed...so vw/vh with max is useless , knowing that it will always be 70% of the user viewport.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends entirely on what you are trying to do. The vh and vw measures are only useful if you want to create blocks relative to the screen size without using jQuery.

The min and max width options are mostly used to in dynamic blocks. For example to prevent empty blocks from collapsing, or blocks with a lot of content to stretch a design element beyond it's intended size.